# Upload image binary to GCP success but can't see image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i have an issue with upload file image (binary) to GCP.
I tested it in postman and it gave me status 200 with an link can open my image. It's succesed.
When i try it in my app, which is coding by react-native, it's also successed but when i opened link which have my uploaded my image, it shows an error like this..
Can anyone help me with this please !!!
Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl0RT.png)

i try to search, using with form-data but...

Comment: Where in GCP are you uploading to?

Comment: hello @Youzef , i'm uploading in google storage.

Comment: Please share the code you have written for uploading the image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ApiProvider.httpPost(CREATE_TASK_REPORT_IMAGE_GCP, lstDataReport, {
      })
        .then(async (response: any) => {
          console.log('percentSum', percentSum);
          await ApiProvider.httpPut(response[0].signedUrl, lstDataReport[0].imageData,
            {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            },
          }).then(((response1: any) => {
          }))
            .catch((err: any) => {
            });
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log('error => ', err);
        });
    });

Comment: here it is. Thank you very much

Comment: i found solution that: i have to tranfer image'uri to binary type